# HTML header and table getting divided into 2 pages

Tags: html

I have a page where there's a header and a table. As the table is large, it is appearing in a completely new line. How can I fix this? Please help, thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Is this really HTML?

Comment: You need to post your code. We can't debug images. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

That might the problem of your word processor putting it on a new line.

You might be able to solve this by giving two line breaks or making two separate tables on each page.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.